# How do i make all faces uv look up

Tags: materials, uv, faces

Im making a backrooms game and i want the wallpaper to face up but depending on the face they are looking at different directions, i arleady tried smart uv project, unwrap, reset and nothing seems to work

[image]

as you can see one is facing up and the other one is facing down and this happened to a lot of other faces and i want to make all of them face up, there is a way i could do this without manually rotating all the faces uvs?

Comment: Hello, with what method did you unwrap, have you tried Cube Projection for example?

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to unwrap, you can use the *Cube Projection* method for walls for example.